# android.view.InflateException but only when testing on Oreo

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I've just got around to testing my app on Oreo and I'm getting what seems like a pretty fundamental fatal exception that I do not get on earlier versions of Android.

```
10-14 21:03:38.004 6833-6833/com.nooriginalthought.yabs E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: com.nooriginalthought.yabs, PID: 6833
                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nooriginalthought.yabs/com.nooriginalthought.yabs.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #428: Binary XML file line #428: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
                                                                           Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #428: Binary XML file line #428: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                           Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #428: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:720)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:788)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:418)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2654)
                                                                              at com.nooriginalthought.yabs.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:155)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

After this I get a bunch of `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException` errors for vector drawable resources - though these work perfectly in earlier versions of Android.

This is all while testing in the Android Studio emulator as I don't have access to an Oreo device.

The errors all seem to be very vague - the only one that points to any line in my code is pointing to the line that calls the correct layout `setContentView(R.layout.main);`.

Line 428 in main.xml (the line in the layout file that is being inflated and that is referred to in the error) is as follows:

```
                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/email_button"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="32dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_yabs_email_144x92"
                        android:backgroundTint="#ffff"
                        android:paddingRight="8dp"
                        android:paddingTop="8dp"
                        android:textColor="#ffff"
                        android:textSize="12dp" />
```

Comment: Please include `R.layout.main` and highlight line 428 (mentioned in the error)

Comment: Line 428 in that layout file is a button that uses one of my vector drawables as a background. The drawables definitely exist in the project as they are displayed correctly when running or testing on any other version of Android I've tried. I'll add that section of the main.xml layout file to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @David Medenjak pointing out that the line referred to in the error was actual a line in my layout file I investigated the vector drawable that was being used in that layout item.

Removing this line from the drawable's XML fixed the error.

```
<path android:fillColor="#000000" android:pathData="" android:strokeWidth="0.48000002"/>
```

I guess a path with no `pathData` was killing things somehow.